# Understanding MapReduce Example

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, word-count

I am beginner with MapReduce, and currently reading the book Data-Intensive Text Processing with MapReduce by Jimmy Lin and Chris Dyer ([link to PDF](http://lintool.github.io/MapReduceAlgorithms/MapReduce-book-final.pdf))

Anyways, the first example the book provides is a word counting algorithm, and I am having trouble understanding why the final output of the reducer is what it is. The example is on page number 23 of the text, figure 2.2. To my understanding X should be 6, Y should be 9, and Z should be 19.

[image]

Comment: You're right, but you should try to contact the author about this, or even submit a pull request to its GitHub page, since that is what the author uses.  Meanwhile, this commentary is not ideally suited for posting to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Where should I post if I have any further questions regarding MapReduce of Hadoop?

Comment: If you have questions on Hadoop or MapReduce, posting them here is a good idea, but your question, at least to me, seems more like a error report for that book.

Comment: I had no intent for the question to be an error report, but more of a clarification question. I am new to MapReduce, so I figured I was not fully understanding the example. Thank anyways.

Comment: For faster, less technical questions, like "am I understanding this right", I can also recommend going to IRC: #hadoop on freenode.  Lots of people usually hang out there, and you can usually get an immediate reply.

Answer (score 1):

Your input file which is fed to mapper will look like:
Rec1: a,1
Rec2: b,2
Rec3: c,3
Rec4: c,6
Rec5: a,5
Rec6: c,2
Rec7;  b,7
Rec8: c,8

Records #1 and #2  &  will be processed by Mapper #1. In this example it is assumed that above file is stored in 4 blocks. Rec #1 & Rec #2 ( & ) in 1st block. Rec #3 and Rec #4 in 2nd block ( & ). Rec #5 and Rec #6 ( & ) will be in 3rd block. Rec 7 and Rec8 will be stored in 4th block Rec7 & Rec8 ().

In Map-Reduce framework one mapper will be invoked for each input split (Logically same as block). Each Mapper will process all the record in an input split.

M1 will take input for ( & ) and emit a as key and 1 as value and emit b as key and 1 as a value. For M2 input is c,3 and c,6 and and it emits key as c and value as 3 and key as c and value is 6 and so on.

And then reducer will accepts those keys and performs its processing.

Hope this clarifies your question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you got confused. Fig 2.2 is not an example of word count algorithm. It shows two level processing of Map-Reduce Frame Work described in section" MAPPERS AND REDUCERS". Fig 2.2 shows simplified view of Map-Reduce. Author wants to show how Map Reduce frame work words with this figure. And this shows how to find maximum of all the values associated with the key. That's y  output is x=5 (max of 1,5) etc.

If you want to read word count algorithm via map-reduce please look at the :

class Mapper
2: method Map(docid a; doc d)
3: for all term t 2 doc d do
4: Emit(term t; count 1)
1: class Reducer
2: method Reduce(term t; counts [c1; c2; : : :])
3: sum   0
4: for all count c 2 counts [c1; c2; : : :] do
5: sum   sum + c
6: Emit(term t; count sum)
Figure 2.3: Pseudo-code for the word count algorithm in MapReduce. The mapper emits an
intermediate key-value pair for each word in a document. The reducer sums up all counts for
each word.

May be confusion arises because picture is pasted first and its number is pasted at the bottom of picture.

Hope this helps !!

Comment: So fig 2.2 and 2.3 are unrelated? And figure 2.2 is not trying to find the max of each word from the total documents? But simply the max of each list fed into the reducer? Why is it the mapper outputs two counts for c, (c,3) and (c,6)?

Comment: Map's input is a Key,Value and Its output is also a Key,Value Pair. In this case figure 2.2 shows Mapper has read the two input key value pairs and emitted two key value pair for C. First is {c,3} & {c,6} After this map phase then short and shuffle occurs for aggregation of values for the key. Since records for one key goes to   same reducer so at only one reducer we have a key and its value {key,<v1,v2>}. So it is just to show Mapper is emitting two key values pair for key C and they got aggregated at a reducer.

Comment: To answer Yes 2.2 is not related for word count algorithm. And figure 2.2 finds max count of a, b & c. Figure just shows there are three reducers. In Map-Reduce records of one key emitted from all the mapper goes to same reducer as R1 {a,<1,5>} . R2 {b,<2,7>} , R3 {c<2,9,8>}. Author has shown 3 different reducers but in reality we can control number of reducer and if we want we can set number of reducers to 1 in that case output from all the mapper will be sent to one reducer only.

Comment: I still don't quite understand why it has two separate counts for c at the second mapper. Is it because it received two separate inputs, and must output at least two separate counts? Or is it arbitrary?

Comment: Your input file which is fed to mapper look as:

Answer (score 0):

A paragraph later:

> Final output is written to the distributed file system, one
>   file per reducer. Words within each file will be sorted
>   by alphabetical order, and each file will contain roughly the
>   same number of words. The partitioner, which we discuss later
>   in Section 2.4, controls the assignment of words to reducers.
>   The output can be examined by the programmer or used as input
>   to another MapReduce program.

As far as I can understand, each Reducer in the example writes its output to a different file. I agree this should be explained *before* the figure as specified in some comments.